# Parallel Environment (PE) on Sun Grid Engine (6.2u5) won't run jobs: "only offers 0 slots"

Tags: gridengine

I have Sun Grid Engine set up (version 6.2u5) on a Ubuntu 10.10 server with 8 cores. In order to be able to reserve multiple slots, I have a parallel environment (PE) set up like this:

```
pe_name            serial
slots              999
user_lists         NONE
xuser_lists        NONE
start_proc_args    /bin/true
stop_proc_args     /bin/true
allocation_rule    $pe_slots
control_slaves     FALSE
job_is_first_task  TRUE
urgency_slots      min
accounting_summary FALSE
```

This is associated with the all.q on the server in question (let's call the server A). However, when I submit a job that uses 4 threads with e.g. qsub -q all.q@A -pe serial 4 mycmd.sh, it never gets scheduled, and I get the following reasoning from qstat:

cannot run in PE "serial" because it only offers 0 slots

Why is SGE saying "serial" only offers 0 slots, since there are 8 slots available on the server I specified (server A)?

The queue in question is configured thus (server names changed):

```
qname                 all.q
hostlist              @allhosts
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       np_load_avg=1.75
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make orte serial
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 1,[D=32],[C=8], \
              [B=30],[A=8]
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/sh
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:60
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            NONE
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  08:00:00
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY,[A=30g], \
              [B=5g]
```

Comment: is your "A" server also defined as execution host?

Answer (score 4):

The allocation rule `$pe_slots` requires you to submit jobs that are of the exact same size as the number of cores on any of your machines. Either change allocation rule to `$fill_up` or try submitting a job which requires 8, 30 or 32 cores.

Comment: The above statement is untrue.  All an allocation_rule of $pe_slots does is force all requested slots to be allocated on a single host.  I have a lot of jobs running on the cluster I admin that demonstrate this.

Comment: It could be one or many hosts, but your job must fill up all cores on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but you can get a lot more information on why grid engine isn't scheduling a job by running `qalter -w p` and `qalter -w v`.  The only caveat is that,at least in some versions, `qalter -w v` doesn't ignore exclusive resources as it should.